# HIbernate: Do not remove OneToOne-related object on soft delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Tl;dr: How can I exclude a specific OneToOne-relation from delete cascade in Hibernate?**

I have the following entities specified in my application:

Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE foos SET deleted = true WHERE foo_id = ?;")
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foo_seq")
@Column(name = "foo_id")
@Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Long id;

... snip ..

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private BarEntity bar;

}
```

Bar:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bars")

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class BarEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "bar_seq")
    @Column(name = "bar_id")
    private Long id;
 ...

}
```

The problem I have is that hibernate now that when I delete FooEntity, hibernate cascades delete to BarEntity and runs into a constraint-violation, as BarEntity is still referenced from FooEntitity and therefore cannot be deleted.

Delete I am running is:

> repository.deleteById(id);

Hibernate query log:

```
Hibernate: 
    UPDATE
        foos 
    SET
        deleted = true 
    WHERE
        foo_id = ?;
Hibernate: 
    /* delete x.x.BarEntity */ delete 
        from
            bar 
        where
            bar_id=?
```

I know I could null reference to Bar in Foo, but I do want to preserve both objects (and their relation) after soft deletion.
I there any way I can achieve this and prevent hibernate from cascading the delete to this particular entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to change `orphanRemoval=true` to `orphanRemoval=false` in the OneToOne Annotation?

Comment: You are right, that's the solution. Can you explain me why it works? From my understanding "orphanRemoval" removes the child entity, when it is no longer referenced. But this is not the case here, since there still *is* a reference from foo to bar.

Comment: I would assume the reason might be your custom delete method. Deleting the parent entity with "orphanRemoval=true" will usually result in the child being deleted aswell because the parent ist not just deactivated but rather removed from the database and thus there is no reference to the child anymore.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks for your answer and explanation. :)